# Flutter hashing string

Tags: flutter

```
    `byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-9").GetBytes(str);
    byte[] hashingbytes = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);
    String hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashingbytes);`
```

this is a c# code When I try to hash similarly in flutter, the data is not the same. How can I do this in Flutter

Comment: Which class is the sha object from can you provide which sha class are you using?

Comment: System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

Comment: Would be helpful if you can share what you have tried in Flutter